# What's the best way to draft emails in Gmail that use variables from Sheets?

Tags: email, gmail, google-spreadsheets, apple-mail

I'm want to draft emails in Gmail that incorporate variables from Sheets. Is there a free tool that does this, or am I better off writing a script?

Crucially, I need to look over the draft emails before sending them, which I find most mail merge tools don't allow.